# Add JEL codes in SVJour3 document class

Tags: sv-classes

I am recently using document class of `svjour3`, as recommended by Finance and Stochastics to submit my paper. However I need to add JEL classification codes in abstract section.

After checking the SVJour3 document class user guide, still I cannot figure out how to add JEL code. Since both the document class and the JEL codes are required by the journal, I believe there is a way to do that. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What's a JEL code and where should it appear?

Answer (score 5):

Simply override the \PACSname in your preamble as follows:

\renewcommand{\PACSname}{\textbf{JEL classification}\enspace}

Then, in your abstract use the \PACS command:

\PACS{JEL code1 \and JEL code2 \and ...}